# when i try to append value in dict its showing key error

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a css file of this type

```
col1    col2
AAA       
 a        1
  a1      1
  a2      1
 b        1
  b1      1
  b2      1
```

i am reading first col based on indentation,"AAA" has 0 no of spaces,"a" "b" has 1 space and "a1","a2" "b1" "b2" has 2 space, now i am printing dict as

```
d={'a':['a1','a2'],'b':['b1','b2']}
```

But what i want is

```
d={'AAA':['a','b'],'a':['a1','a2'],'b':['b1','b2']}
```

i am using code like this

```
reader=csv.DictReader(open("c:/Users/Darshan/Desktop/sss.csv"),dialect="excel")
for row in reader:
    a.append(row['col1'])
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i].count(' ')==1:
            d[a[i]]=[]
            k=a[i]

        else a[i].count(' ')==2:
            d[k].append(a[i])
```

this print this output

```
 d={'a':['a1','a2'],'b':['b1','b2']}
```

so can anyone help me,thanks in advance

Comment: You have an answer that helped -- you should accept it.

Comment: @EthanFurman yest itself i accepted,whats in that,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you just change your for loop to this:

```
# A variable to keep track of the least-nested level of your hierarchy
top_lvl = ''
k = ''
for i in range(len(a)):
    # Pre-compute this value so you don't have to do it twice or more
    c = a[i].count(' ')
    # This case is the topmost level
    if c == 0:
        top_lvl = a[i]
        d[top_lvl] = []
    # This case is the middle level
    elif c == 1:
        d[a[i]]=[]
        k=a[i]
        d[top_lvl].append(k)
    # This case is the most deeply nested level
    else: # c==2
        d[k].append(a[i])
```

In fact now that I'm making everything all sweet, you can probably just iterate through the values in `a` directly, without referring to its values by index. Like so:

```
# A variable to keep track of the least-nested level of your hierarchy
top_lvl = ''
# More descriptive variable names can make everything easier to read/understand
mid_lvl = ''
for val in a:
    # Pre-compute this value so you don't have to do it twice or more
    c = val.count(' ')
    # This case is the topmost level
    if c == 0:
        top_lvl = val
        d[val] = []
    # This case is the middle level
    elif c == 1:
        d[val]=[]
        mid_lvl =val
        d[top_lvl].append(mid_lvl)
    # This case is the most deeply nested level
    else: # c==2
        d[mid_lvl].append(val)
```

Comment: Thanks, you can upvote if you want; also, see my second example. It's a lot cleaner and more readable IMO. BTW this isn't Perl, you don't need to use 1-letter variable names :)

Comment: But if one more variable assume 'c' is their in the level of 'a','b'. Its adding c=[] in dict which i dont need @FrancisW.Usher

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher ur answer was correct, now i changed the question can u help me now,thanks in advance

Comment: Nope! If you want to ask another question, open another post. However I recommend you figure this stuff out on your own, really.

Comment: @FrancisW.Usher http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940090/how-to-create-dict-inside-dict see this link, i opened one more post, pls help now